# Why am I receiving a SqlMapException when inserting data?

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis, ibator

I'm trying to use iBatis to insert some data that get sent by a user in a contact us form.

I'm using a Liferay/Spring MVC/iBatis/MySQL setup but I think the problem is caused by the iBatis configuration. Whenever I try to insert data I see an exception in the logs:

```
com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: There is no statement named contactus.ibatorgenerated_insert in this SqlMap.
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.getMappedStatement(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:231)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.insert(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:367)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.insert(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:82)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.insert(SqlMapClientImpl.java:58)
```

The ibator generated sql map *does* contain an insert query with id "ibatorgenerated_insert" with namespace "contact_us"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>
<sqlMap namespace="contactus">
        <insert id="ibatorgenerated_insert" parameterClass="contactUs.dao.ContactUs">
            <!--
            WARNING - This element is automatically generated by Apache iBATIS ibator, do not modify.
            This element was generated on Thu Apr 07 15:17:57 BST 2011.
            -->
            insert into contactus (email_address, first_name, last_name, company, timestamp,
            status, message)
            values (#emailAddress:VARCHAR#, #firstName:VARCHAR#, #lastName:VARCHAR#, #company:VARCHAR#,
            #timestamp:TIMESTAMP#, #status:VARCHAR#, #message:LONGVARCHAR#)
            <selectKey resultClass="java.lang.Integer" keyProperty="contactusId">
                SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
            </selectKey>
        </insert>
    </sqlMap>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

What can be causing iBatis not to find the statement in the XML file? I assume that it's finding the file since it doesn't report any other kind of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope that you have specified the **contactus.xml** file which contains insert statement in the **SqlMapConfig.xml** as below

```
<sqlMapConfig>
    <properties resource="Connection.properties"/>
    <!-- Configure a built-in transaction manager.  If you're using an        app server, you probably want to use its transaction manager        and a managed datasource -->
<settings cacheModelsEnabled="false" enhancementEnabled="true"
  lazyLoadingEnabled="true" maxRequests="32" maxSessions="1"
    useStatementNamespaces="false" />
  <transactionManager type="JDBC">
    <dataSource type="JNDI">
        <property name="DataSource" value="${connection.datasource}"/>
    </dataSource>
  </transactionManager>
 <!-- List the SQL Map XML files. They can be loaded from the        classpath, as they are here (com.domain.data...) -->
    <sqlMap resource="contactus.xml"/>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

Call without namespace.Something like below

```
sqlMapper.insert("ibatorgenerated_insert",params);
```

Comment: Yes you were right, previously I had `<sqlMap></sqlMap>` in my XML file and thought I could add the configuration into the same file. Now I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to insert data but it seems like a new problem - so I'll create a new question! :P

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `<sqlMapConfig>` element:

```
<settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
```